# Convert CMYK to RGB c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to convert CMYK color mode to RGB mode using c#.

I have tried RasterEdge.DocImageSDK library but it give me errors when building the project.

I have the physical path of the image.

```
 System.Drawing.Image OrjinalResim = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(orj_resim_adi.FullName);
                ResimIslem ri = new ResimIslem(OrjinalResim);
```

Comment: Please paste you code. This is how no one can help you. Are you trying to convert hexadecimal value or something ?

Comment: You will inevitably have trouble converting between CMYK and RGB, as the gamuts are not the same. See marked duplicate for some insight into the difficulty. If you get to a point where you've actually _tried_ something and are still having trouble, post a new question, make sure you include a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you tried, explain precisely what the code does and what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you need help with. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
    public struct CMYK
{
    private double _c;
    private double _m;
    private double _y;
    private double _k;

    public CMYK(double c, double m, double y, double k)
    {
        this._c = c;
        this._m = m;
        this._y = y;
        this._k = k;
    }

    public double C
    {
        get { return this._c; }
        set { this._c = value; }
    }

    public double M
    {
        get { return this._m; }
        set { this._m = value; }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get { return this._y; }
        set { this._y = value; }
    }

    public double K
    {
        get { return this._k; }
        set { this._k = value; }
    }

    public bool Equals(CMYK cmyk)
    {
        return (this.C == cmyk.C) && (this.M == cmyk.M) && (this.Y == cmyk.Y) && (this.K == cmyk.K);
    }
}

public struct RGB
{
    private byte _r;
    private byte _g;
    private byte _b;

    public RGB(byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        this._r = r;
        this._g = g;
        this._b = b;
    }

    public byte R
    {
        get { return this._r; }
        set { this._r = value; }
    }

    public byte G
    {
        get { return this._g; }
        set { this._g = value; }
    }

    public byte B
    {
        get { return this._b; }
        set { this._b = value; }
    }

    public bool Equals(RGB rgb)
    {
        return (this.R == rgb.R) && (this.G == rgb.G) && (this.B == rgb.B);
    }
}

public static RGB CMYKToRGB(CMYK cmyk)
{
    byte r = (byte)(255 * (1 - cmyk.C) * (1 - cmyk.K));
    byte g = (byte)(255 * (1 - cmyk.M) * (1 - cmyk.K));
    byte b = (byte)(255 * (1 - cmyk.Y) * (1 - cmyk.K));

    return new RGB(r, g, b);
}
```

Comment: I have the physical path of the image. Not the values.